# Help connecting to a VPN

Tags: gnome, vpn

I'm having problems connecting to a VPN.

The information I have is:

- VPN Type: L2TP - IPSEC
- Server: 150.xxx.xxx.xxx
- IPSEC PSK: xxxx...
- DNS Suffix: xxx
- Add Static route to xx.x.xx.0/20

I can't give obviously the real data. What I want to know is where everything goes. By the way, the VPN works in Windows perfectly.

[image: img_identity]

[image: img_L2TP]

[image: img_IPv4]

I'm using Gnome 3 as Desktop

Comment: Leave "NT Domain" empty unless you are connecting to a VPN server running on Windows Server and need to specify the Active Directory domain. You wrote username is no need, it most definitely is needed. You can sort out the "DNS Suffix" and static route netmask later after you are able to connect.